# Python: Run only one function async

Tags: asynchronous

I have a large legacy application that has **one** function that is a prime candidate to be executed async. It's IO bound (network and disk) and doesn't return anything.
This is a very simple similar implementation:

```
import random
import time
import requests

def fetch_urls(site):
    wait = random.randint(0, 5)
    filename = site.split("/")[2].replace(".", "_")
    print(f"Will fetch {site} in {wait} seconds")
    time.sleep(wait)
    r = requests.get(site)
    with open(filename, "w") as fd:
        fd.write(r.text)

def something(sites):
    for site in sites:
        fetch_urls(site)
    return True

def main():
    sites = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.reddit.com", "https://www.msn.com"]
    start = time.perf_counter()
    something(sites)
    total_time = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f"Finished in {total_time}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My end goal would be updating the **something** function to run fetch_urls async.
I cannot change **fetch_urls**.

All documentation and tutorials I can find assumes my entire application is async (starting from *async def main()*) but this is not the case.
It's a huge application spanning across multiple modules and re-factoring everything for a single function doesn't look right.

For what I understand I will need to create a loop, add tasks to it and dispatch it somehow, but I tried many different things and I still get everything running just one after another - as oppose to concurrently.

I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replying to myself, it seems there is no easy way to do that with async. Ended up using `concurrent.futures`

```
import time
import requests
import concurrent.futures


def fetch_urls(url, name):
    wait = 5
    filename = url.split("/")[2].replace(".", "_")
    print(f"Will fetch {name} in {wait} seconds")
    time.sleep(wait)
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(filename, "w") as fd:
        fd.write(r.text)

def something(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_url = {
            executor.submit(fetch_urls, url["url"], url["name"]): (url)
            for url in sites["children"]
        }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print("%r generated an exception: %s" % (url, exc))
    return True


def main():
    sites = {
        "parent": "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "children": [
            {"name": "google", "url": "https://google.com"},
            {"name": "reddit", "url": "https://reddit.com"},
        ],
    }
    start = time.perf_counter()
    something(sites)
    total_time = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f"Finished in {total_time}")
```